# How to remove seek bar thumb padding?

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to add seek bar to my app, but when i do i see some padding in seek bar thumb (see image below). How can i remove this padding?

[image]

The xml code of the seek bar is

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:max="10000"
        android:paddingLeft="-10dp"
        android:paddingRight="-10dp"
        android:progress="0"
        android:thumbOffset="-10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: android:thumbOffset="-1dp" Try this. It will help you. OR use this `android:paddingLeft="1dp"` `android:paddingRight="1dp"`

Comment: already tried it doesn't work.

Comment: I have added the full layout code. Though there is only one seekbar in the layout file.

Comment: That's not padding, it's a material design effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code.

No padding shown my side.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
    android:max="10000"
    android:progress="0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```